# Execute shell scrip from Git in specific EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, amazon-ec2

I have a shell script.  Per rule in my organization we should save all the code in GitHub and use it from there. How can I run this script in a specific set of EC2 instances from GitHub using Jenkins?

Comment: What do you mean by "use it from there"? Presumably, you should deploy the code somehow, right?

Comment: This is just a script that needs to be run remotely to execute those commands.  This code cannot be copied or stored physically on the server. The job will be run in Jenkins slave and these commands need to be executed in a set of servers as part of that job.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the use of AWS Systems Manger to run shell commands on your EC2 instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html

You can find a sample use case here: https://ujjwalbhardwaj.me/post/trigger-actions-inside-ec2-instance-on-cloudwatch-events-using-aws-systems